# Why doesn't CCLabelTTF start a new line on @"\n"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
dialogLabel=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(140, 54) hAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:12];
[dialogLabel setString:@"Hello \n World!"];
```

But it shows `@"Hello \n World!"`.

If I use

```
[dialogLabel setString:@"This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long sentence!"];
```

it shows in several lines.

I thought it's a bug of cocos2d and I tried to find the way to solve this problem on Google, however I didn't get anything helpful.

I hope you'll help me with the problem, thanks:)!

Comment: `kCCTextAlignmentCenter` is better than `UITextAlignmentLeft` for a parameter `hAliginment:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10384), `CCLabelTTF` does not (easily?) support this feature, yet `CCLabelBMFont` does.

```
CCLabelBMFont *label2 = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Multi line\nCenter" fntFile:@"bitmapFontTest3.fnt"];
label2.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Apparently there is a method involving more code that makes the same work for `CCLabelTTF` (link above), so you might want to try that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please put back slash.Like @"Hello /\n World!" and check.